# Switch data between multiple identical sheets without losing any of the data

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel workbook that has 20 tabs named after bed numbers for a residence.
Each sheet is formatted identically and contains demographic data for the individual occupying the bed.
The data is entered from a user form.

I need to change bed assignments without requiring the user to reenter all the data.

I thought to address this in one of two ways: I can either create a form that lists the names of those occupying the beds and user will assign bed # to each individual, then rename each sheet, orr pull all the data from each sheet and re insert it to the correct sheet based on the bed change.

I either need to switch data between sheets without losing any of the data or rename all the sheets based on the the user entry.

Comment: If you pulled all the data to fill 20 rows  on another sheet , how many columns would be needed ?

Comment: It's 20 tabs or sheets.  Each sheet has what amounts to a face sheet for an individual.  From your question I think you are recommending to have an extra sheet to temporarily hold the data from first sheet and kind of domino the rest of the data through the other sheets as needed.  This could work.  can you recommend an algorithm that would accomplish this and not miss any of the moves?  which data moves to which sheet would be different each time the user makes bed changes.

Comment: Could you show any sample of how the data looks like and what is your idea: Change the tab name? Tab name and data? Data?

Comment: I was thinking copy to a sheet that holds the data from all 20 tabs, each row holding the data for one sheet. The reallocation done with a form. Then copy back the changes.

Comment: I think this will work,  Thank you.  I will give it a shot.  I think I can work out the code.

Comment: A useful trick is to put the cell references on the bed sheet in the column headers of the data sheet rather than hard coding them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a form like this

[image]

Create a data sheet like with Load and Save buttons.

[image]

Load will fill the data sheet from the bed forms. Reallocate beds in column B and Save back to forms. I have included basic error and validation checks and a backup save after load for added security.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub btnLoad_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet, r As Long
    Dim b As Long, c As Long, lastcol As Long, addr As String
   
    Set wsData = Sheets("Data")
    lastcol = wsData.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For Each ws In Sheets
       If ws.Name Like "Bed #*" Then
            b = CLng(Mid(ws.Name, 4))
            r = b + 3
            wsData.Cells(r, "B") = b
            For c = 3 To lastcol
                addr = wsData.Cells(2, c)
                wsData.Cells(r, c) = ws.Range(addr).Value2
            Next
       End If
    Next
    
    ' save backup
    With Application
       .ScreenUpdating = False
       .DisplayAlerts = False
       wsData.Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Data_" & Format(Now, "yyyymmdd_hhmmss") & ".xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet, msg As String
    Dim b As Long, c As Long, lastcol As Long, addr As String
    
    ' get allocations bed to data row
    Dim dict, r As Long
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For r = 4 To 13
       If Not IsNumeric(Sheets("Data").Cells(r, "B")) Then
           MsgBox "Invalid bed no" & b, vbCritical, r
           Exit Sub
       End If
       b = Sheets("Data").Cells(r, "B")
       ' sanity check
       If dict.exists(b) Then
           MsgBox "Duplicate bed " & b, vbCritical, r
           Exit Sub
        ElseIf b < 1 Or b > 20 Then
           MsgBox "Invalid bed no " & b, vbCritical, r
           Exit Sub
        Else
            dict.Add b, r
        End If
    Next
    
    Set wsData = Sheets("Data")
    lastcol = wsData.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    For Each ws In Sheets
       If ws.Name Like "Bed #*" Then
            b = CLng(Mid(ws.Name, 4))
            r = dict(b) ' data row from dictonary
            ' is there a change
            If r <> b + 3 Then
                For c = 3 To lastcol
                    addr = wsData.Cells(2, c)
                    ws.Range(addr).Value2 = wsData.Cells(r, c)
                Next
                msg = msg & vbLf & "Bed " & b
            End If
       End If
    Next
    
    If msg = "" Then
       MsgBox "No changes made", vbInformation
    Else
       MsgBox "Changes made to " & msg, vbInformation
    End If
    
End Sub
```